# how to retain data in postgres slave after a change in master

Tags: python, postgresql, database-replication

I am using [bitnami Postgres](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/postgresql) docker image for creating my master-slave database.

I am making changes to my master and serving my app using slave.
my script needs to remove a table in order to recreate it with updated data.
But as soon as I delete these tables, they will be removed from slave as well, and hence can cause my app to break.
Is there a way to retain tables on slave until I am done recreating them?

Am I using the right approach and intuition?
Any help is much appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can suspend replication by running this statement on the standby server:

```
SELECT pg_wal_replay_pause();
```

Then, when you are done, you can resume replication with

```
SELECT pg_wal_replay_resume();
```

Note that when you resume replication, the tables on the standby will be deleted as well.  But replay will happen as fast as possible, so the time when you have no tables on the standby will be no longer than necessary.

Concerning permissions: [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-RECOVERY-CONTROL-TABLE) says:

> This function is restricted to superusers by default, but other users can be granted EXECUTE to run the function.

So you could

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON pg_wal_replay_pause() TO some_user;
```

Comment: Thanks @Laurenz for your response, Can this be done using Sqlalchemy, I have been trying to find a way, since my whole script is using sqlalchemy for its Postgres operations

Comment: Surely you can have SQLAlchemy run a `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Thanks man, I have tried that...But its showing me this error `ERROR:  permission denied for function pg_wal_replay_pause`, I have also tried `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO <myuser>;` but the error persists, Please let me know if I'm missing something

Comment: You are missing execute permission on the function. This is not related to table permission.

Comment: So I spent some time on this issue,  turn out [bitnami's postgres docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/postgresql) build's non root containers and after all the effort, I was not able to create and login as root through such a container, and hence cannot run those permission statements

Comment: If you are trying to say that you have no superuser (who is "root"?), yes, that would be a problem if you want to influence replication.

Comment: I have created replication manually, using this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NaPnYQBBdyU&t=1086s) and when I run `SELECT pg_wal_replay_pause();` on slave or master I get `ERROR:  recovery is not in progress
HINT:  Recovery control functions can only be executed during recovery.`  couldn't find anything on this issue, Please let me know what could be the reason behind it? Thanks

Comment: That means that you are not on the standby server.

Comment: can you please answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76512690/pause-replication-on-aws-rds