# pause replication on AWS RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, sqlalchemy, amazon-rds, database-replication

My python script requires replication on the master DB to be stopped for a while to perform all PostgreSQL operations like truncating tables, adding new values to them, and updating the tables as well, I used to do that with this query

`SELECT pg_wal_replay_pause();`

and resume it using this

`SELECT pg_wal_replay_resume();`

the purpose was to replicate all the queries and changes at once on the slave DB(since It is serving my front-end), when I am done making those changes on the master DB

but since I moved to AWS RDS, I cannot seem to stop replication. As this query

`SELECT pg_wal_replay_pause();`

returns

`ERROR:  permission denied for function pg_wal_replay_pause SQL state: 42501`

Is it even possible? if not kindly suggest me another way of doing so.

Comment: Looks like it is not possible. But that's a pointless exercise anyway.

Comment: can you please suggest me any alternative to my approach?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you won't be able to suspend replication then.

An alternative solution would be to perform all your changes in a single transaction. Then they would become visible on the standby server at the same instance, no matter if replication is stopped or not.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I changed everything to single transactions with raw queries as POC, but since my script involves truncating a table and repopulating it, it locks the read access on the same table at my aws read replica and only allows queries on aws read replica when the single transaction in completed, which in my case cas take upto 20-25 mins. I am using a t3.micro, updating cpu only saves a few mins

Comment: Use `DELETE`, followed by `VACUUM`  instead of `TRUNCATE`. It will be slower, but it won't block queries on the standby.

Comment: the `VACUUM` statement returned `psycopg2.errors.ActiveSqlTransaction: VACUUM cannot run inside a transaction block` because I am running it inside a single transaction block, so I just used DELETE, and works perfectly fine. Is there a way around `VACUUM` since recovering deleted space was also important

Comment: Ah, hm, I didn't think of the transaction. No, unfortunately that cannot be done in a transaction.